# .net WCF IIS Application, deployment

Tags: wcf, deployment

I am beginning to see that WCF IIS deployment is no piece of cake, and lots of things break depending on configuration and environment.

Can anyone recommend an online resource that can teach me the art of deployment for WCF IIS Applications.

Thank you

Some of the issues I've already faced when deploying, but not limited to this list:

1. Logging stops working
2. Production server may have SSL enabled
3. Permissions (oh joy!)
4. Proxy Servers may / may not be used in production
5. IIS version differance
6. Windows Server version differances
7. Framework features not enabled in production
8. 32bit vs 64bit issues
9. App gets installed to a virtual directory sitting in the same application as a 
   SharePoint installation
10. App pool running under extremely limited credentials
11. Locale Differances

The list continues, I want to extend my expertise in this area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understanding and identifying the physical architecture of the environment your deploying into will help make sure of your deployment success.  Planning is key.

Like @Kirk mentioned, practice makes perfect.  If you have access to a virtual environment of any sort, create a virtual image with similar characteristics of your deployment environment to  help you out.  Install the same OS, IIS and .NET framework versions and practice deploying to it.

[How To: Create a Service Account for ASP.NET 2.0 Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998297.aspx) will walk you through creating a custom service account (if required) to run your app pool under.  I don't remember if aspnet_regiis.exe grants the account 'logon as a service right'.  Check out the NTRights.exe utility to determine how to do this.

[Security Guidance: ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998258.aspx)  contains some best practices around securing your deployments.

[Improving Web Services Security: Scenarios and Implementation Guidance for WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949034.aspx?rssCatalog) "light reading"

[Extend Your Services Beyond HTTP with WAS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163357.aspx) will walk you through configuring non-http bindings for IIS 7.

MSDN [Patterns and Practices Catalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/practices/bb985515.aspx)

Once you've figured out how to successfully deploy into your environment, automating the deployment process will make sure that it is repeatable.

Answer (score 1):

Practice makes perfect!

But seriously, the best online resource is Google.  So many people experience IIS configuration problems that there are literally thousands of pages on every error I've ever experienced.  You should just push through them one by one, learning as you go...

Comment: Of course, I am assuming you have access to the server & IIS.

Comment: Sometimes not, infact thats another issue on its own, sometimes not even our support guys have access to the server - don't you just love broken telephone communication!

Comment: If you don't have access to the server, then all you can really do is report the error to the person who does - it's their job to ensure the configuration is consistent and accessible.

Answer (score 0):

The only advice I can give is choose your host wisely. I've heard good things about these guys: http://www.discountasp.net/

Also, publish often to avoid surprises.

Answer (score 0):

We have automated all of our WCF service installations, with MSI install packages.

Scott Gu's blog is a good place to start: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/28/vs-2008-web-deployment-project-support-released.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it yet, but Microsoft have recently released an application called [Web Deployment Tool](http://www.iis.net/extensions/WebDeploymentTool), which allows you to package sites and associated IIS settings into a deployment package.  A developer level overview can also be found at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698%28VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

It is no more involved than running it on your dev PC.